# Get the Project URL in WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

How to get the project URL in C# inside the server in my case which is `http://localhost:4333/` because we have this

```
Image _img = Image.GetInstance("http://localhost:4333/logo.PNG");
```

in the server to print the PDF with logo in it then send it to client as **byte[]**

is there something like

```
string _projectUrl = Environment.GetProjectUrl;
Image _img = Image.GetInstance(_projectUrl + "/guavatel.PNG");
```

Answer (score 2):

In WebAPI and more specifically in a context of an `ApiController`, the `Request` property of type `HttpRequestMessage` is different than in MVC applications. Therefore, `HttpRequestMessage` doesn't define a property called `Url`.

For that purpose, you have to use the property called `RequestUri`.

You can get your project base url with this extension method:

```
public static class ApiControllerExtensions
{
    public static string GetBaseUrl(this ApiController controller)
    {
        return string.Concat(controller.Request.RequestUri.Scheme, "://", controller.Request.RequestUri.Authority);
    }
}
```